# Manipulating an iframe embedded site to be responsive

Tags: css, iframe, web

I would like to add an iframe in which to display some other site that I don't have editing access to.

The other, embedded site, isn't responsive-designed at all.

Is it possible to influence the embedded site that's on the iframe using CSS to make it responsive?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible, because that site will have hard-coded width/height values and reducing iframe size will be same as resizing your browser.